# d3js: "Error: <circle> attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN"

Tags: javascript, d3.js

This has been answered before, but none of the answers fit my question

Problem is. I'm writting a very simple code that moves a selected circle to a random position within the parent element. If I do:

```
...
circle.attr('cx', nx)
      .attr('cy', ny)
...
```

Being `nx` and `ny` the new calculated x, y coordinates, it works perfectly. Now, if I use a `transition()`, I got the message `Error: <circle> attribute cy: Expected length, "NaN"`. The most strange thing it only happens with the `cy` attr. With the `cx`, or the `r` attrs it works perfectly, the code I'm trying is:

```
...
circle.transtion()
      .attr('cx', nx)
      .attr('cy', ny)
...
```

I thought it might be related to something the `attr()` returns, so I changed to:

```
...
circle.transtion()
      .attr('cy', ny)
      .attr('cx', nx)
...
```

And got the same error, even if I do

```
...
circle.transtion()
      .attr('cy', ny)
...
```

it doesn't work, but if I do

```
...
circle.transtion()
      .attr('cx', nx)
...
```

it works perfectly

So I got no idea what to look for

---

Of course `cx` and `cy` have valid values, I even tried `.attr('cy', cx)` thinking somehow it might have a NaN value

---

Full code:

```js
ancho = d3.select('#canvas').style('width').slice(0, -2)
alto  = d3.select('#canvas').style('height').slice(0, -2)

cir = d3.select('#cir')

function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

d3.select('#boton').on('click', function() {
    let nx = getRandomInt(ancho)
    let ny = getRandomInt(alto)
    console.log(nx, ny);
    cir.transition()
        .attr('cx', nx)
        .attr('cy', ny)
        .attr('r', getRandomInt(200))
})
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="boton" type="button">Click</button>
<svg id="canvas" width="100%" height="300px">
  <circle id="cir" cy="10" cx="10" r="10">
</svg>
```

---

Thanks a lot for the snippet

I solved it, but I really don't understand why this is happening. As you see in the previous snippet that Alex L placed, it really works on the snippet. That's exactly what I want to do. Now, if I copy that code onto my page (just assuming I'm having some error I can't figure out), it doesn't work either, and produce the same error.

So what I did?

```
d3.select('#boton').on('click', function() {
    let nx = getRandomInt(ancho)
    let ny = getRandomInt(alto)
    console.log(nx, ny);
    cir.transition()
        .attr('cx', nx.toString())
        .attr('cy', ny.toString())
        .attr('r', getRandomInt(200))
})
```

I don't understand why this works. This is absurd. You can pass the `attr` an integer like `.attr('cx', 100)` and works, but if I pass the var which contains an integer it gives me the error message.

If I take out the `.transition()` it works with the vars, tho

Comment: a reproduce codepen will be helpful

Comment: whatever is calculating `ny` is returning `NaN`, like adding an object to a number, or another undefined operation

Comment: No. If I just take away the `transition()` it works. If I use `ny` to set the `cx` it also works

Comment: How do I do a codepen?

Comment: you can visit https://codepen.io/ to make a codepen and then link it in your answer, but you can also just use the built in "snippet" option here - I changed your code to a snippet in your question. For me, it works as expected?

Answer (score -1):

Working example (I think). It works as I would expect it to, without any Javascript changes? (I just added the correct svg tags etc.)

Also working codePen: https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/KKVZMeR

Works for me on Chrome 83.0.4103.116 , FireFox 77.0.1 and Edge 42.17134.1098.0

```js
ancho = d3.select('#canvas').style('width').slice(0, -2)
alto  = d3.select('#canvas').style('height').slice(0, -2)

cir = d3.select('#cir')

function getRandomInt(max) {
    return Math.floor(Math.random() * Math.floor(max));
}

d3.select('#boton').on('click', function() {
    let nx = getRandomInt(ancho)
    let ny = getRandomInt(alto)
    console.log(nx, ny);
    cir.transition()
        .attr('cx', nx)
        .attr('cy', ny)
        .attr('r', getRandomInt(200))
})
```

```css
button {
  width: 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
<button id="boton" type="button">Click</button>
<svg id="canvas" width="100%" height="300px">
  <circle id="cir" cy="10" cx="10" r="10">
</svg>
```

Comment: This is exactly my code. It runs in the snippet, but it fails in my browser. I have tried it both in Opera 68.0.3618.125 and Chrome 83.0.4103.116 and it doesn't work there

Comment: That was my point. I wanted to show that just using your code and adding the correct HTML and SVG tags etc. worked for me no issues. I also have a working codePen - https://codepen.io/Alexander9111/pen/KKVZMeR

Comment: Works for me on Chrome 83.0.4103.116 , FireFox 77.0.1 and Edge 42.17134.1098.0

Comment: The code is pretty much what you showed here, I'm really puzzled. I solved it converting `nx` and `ny` to strings with `nx.toString()`, that's absurd but it works now. If I leave them as integers, it simply doesn't work. Why? I have no idea, and I don't see any other markup that could be causing trouble, my `div`s are quite the same as you show